# iOS: Inverse UIBezierPath (bezierPathWithOvalInRect)

Tags: ios, image, core-graphics, transparency, uibezierpath

I have an jpg Image with a round object in a rect and want to make the envoirement of the round object transparent...

[image: Example]

(Remove red area in this example)

With the help of this [iOS make part of an UIImage transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305285/ios-make-part-of-an-uiimage-transparent) and "UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect" i've got a little success, but this make a path around my object, and I need to invert it, to make the outside and not the inside of the path transparent..

Im not shure where I have to change my code to get the right result..

Here is my code:

```
//BezierPath
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];  

// Create an image context containing the original UIImage.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imgTemp.image.size);
[_imgTemp.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

// Clip to the bezier path and clear that portion of the image.
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddPath(context,bezierPath.CGPath);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextClearRect(context,CGRectMake(0,0,self._imgTemp.image.size.width,self._imgTemp.image.size.height));

// Build a new UIImage from the image context.
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self._imgTemp.image = newImage;
```

Anybody got the resolving?

Comment: Do you only want to make the red become transparent or the black become transparent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To only draw within the black circle you should move `[_imgTemp.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];` to after `CGContextClip(context);` and then remove the `CGContextClearRect( ... )` call entirely:

```
//BezierPath
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];  

// Create an image context containing the original UIImage.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imgTemp.image.size);

// Clip to the bezier path and clear that portion of the image.
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddPath(context,bezierPath.CGPath);
CGContextClip(context);

// Draw here when the context is clipped
[_imgTemp.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

// Build a new UIImage from the image context.
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self._imgTemp.image = newImage;
```

Comment: It's possible to clip the current context to a UIBezierPath with `[bezierPath addClip]`, so you don't have to fiddle with `CGContextRef` directly.