# How to make transparent area uiimage in path

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

In iOS,
I have a image.
Then, I want to make transparent area in specific path of the image.
The below image is some image. And, the heart area is random path to be transparent area.
I have just one full image.
I want to make transparent specific area of image. It is UIImage, not UIImageView. So, I can't use masking.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8306254/2160799
I tried to use this solution, but the heart area was filled with blue color, not transparent. :(
The document explain like this. Because the solution uses imageContext(not window or bitmap contexts), I should not use the function(*CGContext.clear(_:)*)

> If the provided context is a window or bitmap context, Core Graphics clears the rectangle. For other context types, Core Graphics fills the rectangle in a device-dependent manner. However, you should not use this function in contexts other than window or bitmap contexts.

[image]

Comment: UIImage can not display without imageview!!

Comment: @SPatel I know. The key point is the image processing.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below snippet. Here you would be creating an imagecontext using the api `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_:_:_:)` and specified the opaque parameter as **false** which would make the end image transparent.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, 0)
image.draw(at: .zero)
if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
    context.setBlendMode(.clear)
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
    context.fillPath()

    let capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Comment: I can't. In that case, the clear area was filled with blue color, I described.

Comment: Have you tried creating a context with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions api?

Comment: Yes, I tried using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions API. It is same result. :(

Comment: Are you sure that you are not drawing anything else into the context?

Comment: func clip(inPath path: CGPath) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        defer {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        draw(at: .zero)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }

        context.addPath(path)
        context.clip()
        context.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        return image
    }

Comment: This is my code. It is extension function of UIImage

Comment: @strawnut I've updated the snippet with blendmode. Can you try the same?

Comment: Oh no... I am so sorry. The before codes are successful. I had tried to capture function: UIGraphicsImageRenderer. The problem is in here. Sorry you won